# Magento: hide custom module Block depending on session variable

Tags: magento

I have my custom module. And there I create my block type. Like this:

```
class My_Module_Block_Subscribe extends Mage_Core_Block_Template {
    ...
}
```

How can I show/hide this block depending on session variable ?

Comment: to hide custom module block you can do that on phtml file, here i couldn't figure out why are you in module block php file, will you please elaborate ?

Comment: I thought its a bad practice to work with sessions in template file. So maybe there is the way to do it in Block class (in construct function for example)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the answer I came up with

```
 class My_Module_Block_Subscribe extends Mage_Core_Block_Template {

   public function renderView(){
     $check = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getMyVar(); 
     if(!$check){
        Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setMyVar(1); 
        return parent::renderView();
     }else{
        return false;
     }
   }
     ...
}
```